# С какой библиотекой лучше всего работать с изображением в pygame?

Tags: pygame, поиск-библиотек

Требования к библиотеке: наложение масок, прозрачный фон, возможность генерировать векторную картинку, и быстрое отображение в окне pygame. До этого я работал только с PIL. Но её не достаточно. Хотелось бы узнать какие библиотеки лучше всего подходят для этих требований.

Comment: pygame работает с вектором?

Comment: Возможно подойдёт OpenCV, там больше возможностей обрабатывать изображения чем в PIL